# Adding row with jquery to a table and populate the last tr with element

Tags: jquery

I have a table like this

HTML

```
<table id='tab_imput'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id='eotp'>    
                <option>...</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id='cc'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id='dest'>    
                <option>...</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id='quot'>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to add rows to a table through a loop (imput) and fill each element with data, it looks good for the first line but doesn't work for the next ones, any help will be very appreciated. thank you

here is my code :

```
$.each(imput, function( index, value ) {
    eotp = $('#tab_imput tbody>tr:last').find($("select[id^='eotp']"));
    eotp.attr('value',imput[index].EOTP).attr('selected', 'selected');
    dest = $('#tab_imput tbody>tr:last').find($("select[id^='dest']"));
    dest.attr('value',imput[index].DESTINATION).attr('selected', 'selected');
    tr = eotp.closest("tr");
    $.post("ajax/ajax_imputation.php", {eotp_val: imput[index].EOTP}, function(response){
        tr.find("#cc").val(response);
    });
    $.post("ajax/ajax_imputation.php", {dest: 'ok', id_dest:imput[index].DESTINATION}, function(response){
        tr.find("#quot").val(imput[index].QUOTITE);
    });
    if(index > 1){
        $('#tab_imput tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#tab_imput tbody>tr:last');
    }
});
```

Comment: What does `imput` look like? Also `id`'s should be unique within your DOM ; as you are cloning the row shown you are creating multiple items with the same `id`, consider using `class`es instead.

Comment: imput is the result of this imput = jQuery.parseJSON(response), I will try with classes instead

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, your algo looks like this:

1. get the last row from the table;
2. fill it with all the necessary data;
3. copy the last row to use it for the next iteration (providing that it isn't the first iteration).

Please bear in mind that elements are indexed starting from 0 and not from 1 in $.each function. Your flow looks like this:

1. Iteration 1 (index 0) - fill the first row;
2. Iteration 2 (index 1) - fill the first row again;
3. Iteration 3 (index 2) - fill the same row again, add new row to the later use;
4. Iteration 4 (index 3) and so on - finally it starts to work as expected.

Isn't it the source of the error? If so, maybe it's better to clone the row ahead of filling it with data for every iteration except of the first one.